# Check if client date and time and server date and time are in sync

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, datetime

I have an angular application, where there are actions that an user can perform. I don't want the user to be able to perform the operations for a back dated or future dated date.

I am using JavaScript date object for getting the current date and passing it to server API. At the API, I check for the correctness of the date and accordingly inform the user in case the date does not match my server date.

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();`

However, there are 2 issues that I am facing, 
1. After changing the system date on windows OS, it takes a lot of time (sometimes more than 10 seconds) for the date object to sync with the system date.
2. The timezone of the client system might not be same as the server time zone.

Can you please tell what is the best mechanism to achieve this behavior.

Comment: 1. you can't fix the OS time from a browser, so not sure why you mentioned it, 2. Always work with UTC time.

Comment: Why do you even care about the client time?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen because im sending that as header to my REST API where this is checked with server date.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I want to check if it does not match server date. I will not allow that operation to user.

Comment: Take care to correctly spell JavaScript so as to avoid search collision with Java.